# Does chaning the owner of /var folder and subfolder make problem?

Tags: command-line, permissions

I wanted to copy many files in /var folder and it made me slow to use the console (because the owner is root) so I changed the owner of `/var` folder and all if its subfolder to my user. 
After restarting my system, my system can't start and throw low graphic error and it said none of your devices can not be detected.
So I go to terminal and try to install my graphic driver but while installing I got these error:

```
/usr/bin/mandb: can't chmod /var/cache/man/nl/CACHEDIR.TAG :operation not permitted
```

How should I solve this?
I use sudo to install driver

Comment: That was a grave mistake to change the ownership of `/var` like that!

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is copying all your data and reinstall 
If you have a /home partition this will be very simple, at the partitioning section of the installation select "Manual" mode and tell the partitioner not to format /home and mount it at the same location